# Retrieve ResourceBundle Java .properties from source code

Tags: java, properties, resourcebundle

I would like to write a script to list Java properties files that are meant to be translated (i.e. Used by ResourceBundle) by scanning the source code.

Just wondering whether it can be done by regex pattern, or it can only be obtained from Runtime?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just search your project directories for .properties files?

Comment: Indeed, simple find can get all the .properties files. But does that mean all .properties files are meant to be translated?